# Why can't i change my Inner HTML via a JS function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set a dynamic text into a Side navigation bar.
When i click the button to open my JS openNav(), side panel shows up, but i cant change (Dynamically) text in it.

Hope i made myself clear enough, first time with JS tonight ;)

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
<p id="dateres">t</p>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "400px";
  document.getElementById("dateres").InnerHTML = "test";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}

</script>
```

I expect that "Dateres" HTML element to be "Test" and not t like i have.

Comment: How is this a "php" question?

Comment: My bad, Sorry got it changed

Comment: Can you show the code that actually calls `openNav`?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Have you tried using [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) (not `InnerHTML`)?

Assuming a bit of code you have is missing this sample might help:

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "400px";
  document.getElementById("dateres").innerHTML = "test";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">open</a>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <p id="dateres">t</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, it actually worked... Sorry about that XD  Thx a lot

Comment: What actually worked?

Comment: putting "innerHTML" instead of "InnerHTML"

Comment: Questions caused by typographical errors should be closed as such, not answered. (Not my downvotes, but I'm fairly confident that is why they are cast.)